# wie sagt man "so far" in Deutsch

Tags: english-to-german

Ich möchte die Übersetzung von "so far" wissen. Sagen wir "bisher" oder "so weit".

Wenn beides möglich ist, wann benutzen wir "bisher" und wann "so weit"?

Zum beispiel, wenn ich sagen möchte, "I have not finished my work so far", wie kann das man sagen?

Comment: Depends on context. One is figurative, the other literal.

Comment: I'd rather translate with *bis jetzt*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bisher wird immer dann verwendet, wenn es um etwas zeitliches geht, wie eine Aufgabe, die bis zu diesem **Zeit**punkt noch nicht erledigt wurde.

> Ich habe meine Arbeit bisher noch nicht erledigt.

So weit wird verwendet, wenn wenn es sich um räumliche oder metaphorisch räumliche Angelegenheiten geht.

> Ich mag die Sendung nicht, aber die Fernbedienung is so weit weg.

oder

> So weit geht es ihm gut.

Zudem gibt es noch die Konjunktion `soweit`, die die eigentliche Aussage einschränkt.

> Soweit ich weiß, haben wir morgen frei.

Comment: Isn't the "bisher" in the first example kind of superfluous? You could say "Ich habe meine Arbeit noch nicht erledigt". The sentence feels a bit "off" to me, though I can't say exactly why.  (native German speaker, but no language expert).

Answer (score 2):

1. **Bisher** war alles in Ordnung (example from [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bisher))
2. Unsere **bisherigen** Bemühungen waren vergeblich = "Our previous endeavors were in vain"
3. **Bisher** war das immer in Ordnung = Until now, it was always ok.
4. **So weit**, so gut (colloquial, common saying) = "so far, so good"
5. **So weit** kommt es noch (colloquial, common saying) = (sarcastic) "this will never happen"
6. **So weit** das Auge reicht (colloquial, common saying) = "as far as the eye can see"
7. **So weit** ich weiß ist es schwer, deutsch zu lernen = as far as I know, it is difficult to learn German
8. **Bisher** dachte ich immer, es ist schwer deutsch zu lernen. Aber jetzt habe ich ja einen Duden.

Note that in combination with *bisher*, past tense is often used as it means something similar to "until now". (Duden: "von einem unbestimmten Zeitpunkt an bis zum heutigen Tag, bis jetzt")

*So weit* can mean a distance (see example 4), or in example 4 it also means "so far" but does not necessarily refer to a distance, (similar to "so far").

So in both, you have a comparison as something which happened previously (until now or until here) and often inferring that this is now changing or may no longer be the case.

*Bisher*, I would use in the sense of "in the past and until now, previously".

In the example 7, you could not replace "so weit" with "bisher" - it means "as far as I know" - meaning I am letting you know my knowledge is somewhat limited. But not that my knowledge lies in the past.

I hope this is helpful. I get that it is not so easy to decide what to use.

Tip:

1. Refer to "Duden" to get the exact definition, like in a dictionary
2. Read, listen to people etc. to get the "living" examples